# Huffy 24 Alpine mountain bike POWER shifter compatibility

Tags: compatibility

I need a compatible front and rear shifters for a Huffy Alpine 24" mountain bike. It presently has POWER shift shifters.

Comment: Do note this bike is pretty low-end, so don't go spending a lot of money on parts.  Used 3x8 shifters would be ideal, though new inner/outer cables would be reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

A 24 gear bike means you have 8 sprockets in the rear and 3 on the crank. Any shifters for 3 front gears and 8 rear will work, that match the manufacturers of the derailleurs.

If derailleurs are Shimano you need Shimano shifters. If the derailleurs are SRAM you need SRAM shifters.

Comment: I'd bet that it has shimano tourney grade shifters, or shimano-with-no-name level.

Comment: Huffy Alpine 24" means that it has 24 inch wheels. Everything I can find on this bike indicates that it's an 18 speed. I believe the brand of derailleur on the bike is "POWER" based on the question. If he purchased "equivalent" Shimano or SRAM derailleurs would you trust that the twist shifters are compatible?